# plotGoogleMaps R package on CMS

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-maps, joomla

I'm using the R package plotGoogleMaps to plot a map like [this](http://www.fabioveronesi.net/Blog/Map_GoogleMaps_small.html) and it works: I get an html file like this and an image for the legend.

I'd like to be able to show this result in a article in Joomla or another CMS, like I would normally do with an image (I don't want to lose the CSS and style of my site), but I don't know how to do it.

As you can see from the source of the example, the file includes two long scripts (one of them is in a link) and I don't know how to include them in the header of my article.

A secondary problem (less important) is that it would be easier to use this function, if it would separate the html that should go in the article from the scripts and the CSS style that should be in the header, so that I don't have to cut and paste everytime, to split these elements and put them in the right place.

I've inserted a simple, shorter, example (the legend is not visible, because it was a separated image) here with just one small polygons and only one variable, so it should be easier to understand the structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <style type="text/css">  
 html { height: 100% ; font-size: small} 
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }

 #Map { float: left;
 width:800px;
 height:600px; }

 #cBoxes {float: left;
width:200px;
height: 600px;
overflow:auto} 

</style> 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.18"> </script>  

 <script language="javascript"> 
  
 USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView(); 
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
      this.bounds_ = bounds;
      this.image_ = image;
      this.map_ = map;
      this.div_ = null;
      this.setMap(map); }
USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      var div = document.createElement("DIV");
      div.style.border = "none";
      div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
      div.style.position = "absolute";
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = "100%";
      img.style.height = "100%";
      div.appendChild(img);
      this.div_ = div;
      this.div_.style.opacity = 0.7;
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);}
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
        var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
        var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
        var div = this.div_;
        div.style.left = sw.x + "px";
        div.style.top = ne.y + "px";
        div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + "px";
        div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + "px";} 
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() { 
 this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);} 
USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() { if (this.div_) { this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";} } 
USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {if (this.div_) {  this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";}} 
       USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() { 
 if (this.div_) { 
  if (this.div_.style.visibility == "hidden") {  
   this.show(); 
  } else { 
  this.hide(); } } } 
 USGSOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function() {
          if (this.getMap()) {
            this.setMap(null);
          } else {
            this.setMap(this.map_);}}
 function setOpacR(Raster,textname) { 
  opac=0.01*parseInt(document.getElementById(textname).value) 
    Raster.div_.style.opacity= opac } 

 
 var GoogleMap  
 var  polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603 =[] ; 
 var polygon= new google.maps.Polygon({ 
 paths:[ new google.maps.LatLng( 43.861701965332 , 10.7270231246949 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8648071289063 , 10.7138719558716 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.86967086792 , 10.7096805572511 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8817100524903 , 10.6950511932374 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.882724761963 , 10.6946687698365 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8834533691406 , 10.6946153640748 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8914604187013 , 10.6955518722535 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9005165100098 , 10.6986227035522 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9016075134278 , 10.6991891860961 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9121093750001 , 10.7056283950807 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9124259948731 , 10.70609664917 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9165954589843 , 10.7151222229004 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9173736572266 , 10.7183818817138 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9156303405762 , 10.7193155288697 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9152069091798 , 10.719415664673 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9097976684571 , 10.7180519104004 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9024848937989 , 10.7170953750611 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.9018325805665 , 10.7173252105712 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8986053466798 , 10.7188882827759 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8957862854004 , 10.7206497192383 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8920631408693 , 10.7215881347657 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8915939331056 , 10.7216873168945 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8911895751954 , 10.7215261459351 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8880500793458 , 10.7201528549194 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8791160583496 , 10.7157011032104 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8631248474121 , 10.725196838379 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8628540039062 , 10.7253637313843 ),
new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8625869750978 , 10.7256422042847 ),
 new google.maps.LatLng( 43.861701965332 , 10.7270231246949 )], 
map:GoogleMap, 
 clickable:true,
 fillColor: "#00FF00",
 strokeColor: "", 
 strokeOpacity:1,
 fillOpacity:0.7,
 strokeWeight:1,
 geodesic:true,
 zIndex:null});
polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603.push(polygon); 

function showR(R,boxname, map) {
  R.setMap(map);
  document.getElementById(boxname).checked = true; }

function hideR(R,boxname) {
R.setMap(null);
document.getElementById(boxname).checked = false; }

function showO(MLPArray,boxname, map ) { 
for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) { 
MLPArray[i].setMap(map); } 
document.getElementById(boxname).checked = true; }

function hideO(MLPArray,boxname) { 
for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) { 
MLPArray[i].setMap(null);} 
document.getElementById(boxname).checked = false; } 

function boxclick(box,MLPArray,boxname, map) { 
if (box.checked) { showO(MLPArray,boxname, map); 
}else {  hideO(MLPArray,boxname);} }

function setOpac(MLPArray,textname){
opacity=0.01*parseInt(document.getElementById(textname).value) 
for(var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) {
MLPArray[i].setOptions({strokeOpacity: opacity, fillOpacity: opacity}); }}

function setOpacL(MLPArray,textname) {
opacity=0.01*parseInt(document.getElementById(textname).value) 
for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++) {
MLPArray[i].setOptions({strokeOpacity: opacity});}}

function setLineWeight(MLPArray,textnameW){
weight=parseInt(document.getElementById(textnameW).value)
for (var i = 0; i < MLPArray.length; i++){
MLPArray[i].setOptions({strokeWeight: weight}); } }

function legendDisplay(box,divLegendImage){
element = document.getElementById(divLegendImage).style;
if (box.checked){ element.display="block";} else {  element.display="none";}}

function boxclickR(box,R,boxname, map) {
if (box.checked){
showR(R,boxname,map); } else { hideR(R,boxname);} }

function legendDisplay(box,divLegendImage){
element = document.getElementById(divLegendImage).style; 
if (box.checked){ element.display="block";} else {  element.display="none";}}  
 function initialize() { 
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8895378112793 , 10.7108192443848 ) ; 
 
 var myOptions = { zoom: 12 , 
 center: latlng , 
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID  ,
 disableDefaultUI: false  ,
 disableDoubleClickZoom: false  ,
  draggable: true  ,
  keyboardShortcuts:  true  ,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT}  ,
  navigationControl: true  ,
 navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT}  ,
 noClear: false  ,
 scaleControl: true  ,
 scaleControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ScaleControlStyle.STANDARD}  ,
  scrollwheel: true  ,
 streetViewControl: false } ; 
 
 GoogleMap= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"),myOptions); 
 
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "", disableAutoPan:false, maxWidth :330, pixelOffset :null, position :new google.maps.LatLng( 43.8901079074412 , 10.7096781253779 ) }); 
 google.maps.event.addListener(polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603[0] ,"click",function(event){ 

 infowindow.setContent("poveri : 28 <br>"); 

 infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

 infowindow.open(GoogleMap)});   
showO(polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603,"polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603box",GoogleMap);  google.maps.event.addListener(  GoogleMap , 'rightclick', function(event) {
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    alert('Lat=' + lat + '; Lng=' + lng);});   
 }
</script> 
 </head> 
 <body onload="initialize()"> 
  <div id="Map"></div>  

                           
 <div id="cBoxes"> 
<table border="0"> 
 <tr> 
  <td> 
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603box" 
                                 onClick='boxclick(this,polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603,"polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603box",GoogleMap);' /> <b> Economic Data<b> </td> </tr> 
 
 <tr> <td> 
 <input type="text" id="polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603text" value="50" onChange='setOpac(polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603,"polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603text")' size=3 /> 
                                 Opacity (0-100 %) </td> </tr> 
 
 <tr>  <td> 
 <input type="text" 
                                 id="polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603W" value="1" onChange='
                                 setLineWeight(polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603,"polyaXxcxxpoverixxX9603W")' 
                                 size=3 /> Line weight (pixels) </td> </tr> 
  
 <tr>  <td> <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" id="boxLegend44c26773e95" onClick='legendDisplay(this,"Legend44c26773e95");' /> LEGEND </td> </tr>  <tr> <td>poveri</td> </tr>
                                    <tr> <td> <div style="display:block;" id="Legend44c26773e95"> <img src="Legend44c26773e95.png" alt="Legend" height="70%"> </div>
                           </td> </tr> 
 </table> 
  <hr> 
 </div> 
 </body>  
  </html>
```

I've tried to publish the code of the first example in Joomla with the CodeMirror Editor (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839930/joomla-3-cant-add-script-to-article)), but it didn't work. I don't know very much about Joomla, so I can't experiment very much: I am afraid the site I'm working with could crash and I have never installed Joomla, so it would be really difficult and long for me to try safe tests (Joomla is the only CMS I've tried, but my knowledge is really low).

Comment: In my opinion your question could be good but I think you have to work a little bit more on it. First, links tend to get broken with time, so if you could include e.g. parts of your html (definitivelly not the "long script" in full, but at least the beginning and the end of it). Second, what have you tried? For example, what happens if you take your CMS, and publish your entry, adding the html of the graph and including the 2 scripts? (I don't know Joomla, but I guess in any CMS you can publish html). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: it's my first question in this site.

I've just included a shorter example (but complete: full html with embedded CSS and scripts), using just one polygon of a small administrative area and just one variable, so it should be easier to understand the structure. I've also added more info about what I've done to test it on Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could probably be using an [iframe tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). It allows to embed another document within the current HTML document.

That's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.fabioveronesi.net/Blog/Map_GoogleMaps_small.html" target="Map" height="1500px" width=1500 ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```